# passing data from activity to fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, nullpointerexception, android-activity

I have created a fragmentactivity (MainActivity) which has a viewpager , in that i have 3 listfragments. When a listitem is pressed in one of the list fragment (AllPatient) another fragmentactivity(PrescAct) opens up containing a viewpager with 3 fragments.

My issue is , when AllPatient list item is pressed , patient_id is passed to PrescAct , which in turn passes that value to fragment DocPresc. I am getting Null Pointer Exception at  `pid = b.getString("TAG_PATIENT_ID1");` in DocPresc.class.

Please suggest , I am stuck at this issue for quite sometime.

Below is the code.

MainActivity FragmentActivity :

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    static AppSectionsPagerAdapter mAppSectionsPagerAdapter;

    ViewPager mViewPager;
    SearchView mSearchView;
    MenuItem menuSearch;
    Boolean flag = false;
    String pid;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        this.getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

        setupActionBar();
        //getActionBar().setTitle("All Patients");

        mAppSectionsPagerAdapter = new AppSectionsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());


        // Set up the ViewPager, attaching the adapter and setting up a listener for when the
        // user swipes between sections.
        mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
        mViewPager.setAdapter(mAppSectionsPagerAdapter);
        mViewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(3);
        mViewPager.setCurrentItem(0);
        mViewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(new OnPageChangeListener() 
        {
            public void onPageSelected(int position) 
            {
                //mAppSectionsPagerAdapter.getItemPosition(getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(position));
                //getActionBar().setTitle(mAppSectionsPagerAdapter.getPageTitle(position));
            //  getActionBar().setTitle(getTitle(position));
                //mAppSectionsPagerAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

                if(position==0){
                    getActionBar().setTitle("All Patients");
                    flag = true;
                //  menuSearch.setVisible(true);
                    //menuSearch.
                    invalidateOptionsMenu();

                }
                if(position==1){
                    getActionBar().setTitle("All Doctors");
                    flag=false;
                //  menuSearch.setVisible(false);
                    invalidateOptionsMenu();
                }
                else
                    getActionBar().setTitle("All Nurses");
                invalidateOptionsMenu();

            }

            public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) 
            {

            }

            public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) 
            {
                if (state == ViewPager.SCROLL_STATE_DRAGGING)
                {

                }
                if (state == ViewPager.SCROLL_STATE_IDLE)
                {

                }
            }
        });
    }
    /**
     * A {@link FragmentPagerAdapter} that returns a fragment corresponding to one of the primary
     * sections of the app.
     */
    public static class AppSectionsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

        public AppSectionsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
            super(fm);
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int i) {
            switch (i) {
            case 0:
                // The first section of the app is the most interesting -- it offers
                // a launchpad into the other demonstrations in this example application.

                return new AllPatient();


            case 1:

                //Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,abc.class);
                return new AllDoctors();



            case 2:
                return new AllNurses();
            }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return 3;
        }
    }
}
```

AllPatient ListFragment :

```
public class AllPatient extends ListFragment {


    // Creating JSON Parser object
    JSONParser jParser = new JSONParser();

    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> productsList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>>();

    // url to get all products list
    private static String url_all_patients = "http://192.168.44.208/get_all_patients.php";

    // JSON Node names
    private static final String TAG_SUCCESS = "success";
    private static final String TAG_PRODUCTS = "products";
    private static final String TAG_PATIENT_ID = "patient_id"; 
    private static final String TAG_PATIENT_NAME = "patient_name";

    JSONArray products = null;

    Context ctx;
    String pid;
    EditText inputSearch;
    ListAdapter adapter;
    ListView lv;


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.patient_list, container, false);
        //ListView lv;

    //  lv = (ListView)view.findViewById(android.R.id.list);

        //ListView v = getListView();
        getActivity().getActionBar().setTitle("All Patients");






        new LoadAllPatients().execute();




        return view;        
    }    





    @Override
    public void onListItemClick(ListView lv, View v, int position, long id) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        onAttach(getActivity());
        //lv.setAdapter(adapter);


        String id1 = ((TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.pid)).getText().toString();
        System.out.println("all  patient"+id1);

        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        bundle.putString("TAG_PATIENT_ID",id1 );
        System.out.println("bundle"+id1);
        Intent i = new Intent(getActivity(),PrescAct.class);
        i.putExtras(bundle);
        startActivity(i);





        //passData(date);


        Toast.makeText(
                getActivity(), 
                getListView().getItemAtPosition(position).toString(), 
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }





    class LoadAllPatients extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {


        protected String doInBackground(String... args) {
            // Building Parameters
            List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
            // getting JSON string from URL
            JSONObject json = jParser.makeHttpRequest(url_all_patients, "GET", params);

            // Check your log cat for JSON reponse
        Log.d("All Patients: ", json.toString());

            try {
                // Checking for SUCCESS TAG
                int success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);

                if (success == 1) {
                    // products found
                    // Getting Array of Products
                    products = json.getJSONArray(TAG_PRODUCTS);

                    // looping through All Products
                    for (int i = 0; i < products.length(); i++) {
                        JSONObject c = products.getJSONObject(i);

                        // Storing each json item in variable
                        String id = c.getString(TAG_PATIENT_ID).toUpperCase();
                        String name = c.getString(TAG_PATIENT_NAME).toUpperCase();

                        // creating new HashMap
                        HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

                        // adding each child node to HashMap key => value
                        map.put(TAG_PATIENT_ID, id);
                        map.put(TAG_PATIENT_NAME, name);

                        // adding HashList to ArrayList
                        productsList.add(map);  
                        Collections.sort(productsList, new Comparator<Map<String, String>>() {

                            public int compare(Map<String, String> o1, Map<String, String> o2) {
                                String name1 = o1.get("patient_name");
                                String name2 = o2.get("patient_name");
                                if (name1 == null) return -1;
                                return name1.compareTo(name2);
                            }
                        });

                    }
                } else {

                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return null;
        }


        /**
         * After completing background task Dismiss the progress dialog
         * **/
        protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
            // dismiss the dialog after getting all products
            //  pDialog.dismiss();
            // updating UI from Background Thread

            getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {

                    ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(
                            getActivity(), productsList,
                            R.layout.list_item1, new String[] { TAG_PATIENT_ID,
                                TAG_PATIENT_NAME},
                                new int[] { R.id.pid, R.id.name });
                    // updating listview
                    //setListAdapter(adapter);
                    setListAdapter(adapter);
                    inputSearch = (EditText)getView().findViewById(R.id.inputSearch);
                    inputSearch.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

                        @Override
                        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence cs, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3) {
                            // When user changed the Text
                            //ListView lv = getListView();
                            ((SimpleAdapter) getListAdapter()).getFilter().filter(cs);  
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1, int arg2,
                                int arg3) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                        }

                        @Override
                        public void afterTextChanged(Editable arg0) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                        }
                    });



                }

             });

        }







    }
```

Here is PrescAct FragmentActivity :

```
public class PrescAct extends FragmentActivity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    static AppSectionsPagerAdapter mAppSectionsPagerAdapter;

    ViewPager mViewPager;
    SearchView mSearchView;
    MenuItem menuSearch;
    Boolean flag = false;
    String pid;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.prescact);

        this.getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

        setupActionBar();
        //getActionBar().setTitle("All Patients");
        // Getting value of pid from all patient
        Intent i = getIntent();

         Bundle extras = i.getExtras();
         pid  = extras.getString("TAG_PATIENT_ID");
         System.out.println("Pid in prescact"+pid);
        // Bundle bundle = new Bundle();

        /* bundle.putString("TAG_PATIENT_ID",pid);
         Intent m = new Intent(PrescAct.this,DocPresc1.class);
            m.putExtras(bundle);*/
    //Passing pid value to the list fragment        
        Bundle b = new Bundle();
        b.putString("TAG_PATIENT_ID1",pid);
        Fragment f = new DocPresc1();
        f.setArguments(b);





        mAppSectionsPagerAdapter = new AppSectionsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());


        // Set up the ViewPager, attaching the adapter and setting up a listener for when the
        // user swipes between sections.
        mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager1);
        mViewPager.setAdapter(mAppSectionsPagerAdapter);
        mViewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(3);
        mViewPager.setCurrentItem(2);
        mViewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(new OnPageChangeListener() 
        {
            public void onPageSelected(int position) 
            {
                //mAppSectionsPagerAdapter.getItemPosition(getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(position));
                //getActionBar().setTitle(mAppSectionsPagerAdapter.getPageTitle(position));
            //  getActionBar().setTitle(getTitle(position));
                //mAppSectionsPagerAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

                if(position==0){
                    getActionBar().setTitle("Prescription1");
                    flag = true;
                //  menuSearch.setVisible(true);
                    //menuSearch.
                    invalidateOptionsMenu();

                }
                if(position==1){
                    getActionBar().setTitle("Prescription2");
                    flag=false;
                //  menuSearch.setVisible(false);
                    invalidateOptionsMenu();
                }
                else
                    System.out.println("today fragment");
                    getActionBar().setTitle("Today's Prescription");
                invalidateOptionsMenu();

            }

            public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) 
            {

            }

            public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) 
            {
                if (state == ViewPager.SCROLL_STATE_DRAGGING)
                {

                }
                if (state == ViewPager.SCROLL_STATE_IDLE)
                {

                }
            }
        });
    }
    /**
     * A {@link FragmentPagerAdapter} that returns a fragment corresponding to one of the primary
     * sections of the app.
     */
    public static class AppSectionsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

        public AppSectionsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
            super(fm);
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int i) {
            switch (i) {
            case 0:
                // The first section of the app is the most interesting -- it offers
                // a launchpad into the other demonstrations in this example application.

                return new AllPatient();


            case 1:

                //Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,abc.class);
                return new AllDoctors();



            case 2:
                System.out.println("today fragment called");
                return new DocPresc1();
            }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return 3;
        }
    }
```

Here is DocPresc Fragment :

```
public class DocPresc1 extends ListFragment {

    //public static Context ctx;
    JSONParser jParser = new JSONParser();

    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> productsList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>>();

        String pid;
        JSONArray products = null;
        EditText ailm,date,comment;
        Button delete;
        ListAdapter adapter;
        JSONParser jsonParser = new JSONParser();

        // single product url
        private static final String url_patient_presc = "http://192.168.44.208/get_prescription.php";


        // JSON Node names
        private static final String TAG_SUCCESS = "success";
        private static final String TAG_PRODUCTS = "products";
      //  private static final String TAG_PATIENT_ID = "patient_id";
        private static final String TAG_AIL = "ailment";
        private static final String[] TAG_MED = {"medicine_id","medicine_id2"};
        private static final String TAG_D1 = "qty1";
        private static final String TAG_D2 = "qty2";
        private static final String TAG_D3 = "qty3";
        private static final String TAG_DATE = "prescription_date";
        private static final String TAG_COM = "comment";
        private static final String TAG_PRESCRIPTION = "prescription_id";
        //private static final String TAG_DID = "dosage_id";
      //  private static final String TAG_MED1_D1 = "m1dosage";
        private static final String[] TAG_MED_D = {"m1dosage","m2dosage"};

        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                Bundle savedInstanceState) {

            View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.docpresc1, container, false);
           // setContentView(R.layout.docpresc);
            StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder()
              .detectDiskReads().detectDiskWrites().detectNetwork() // StrictMode is most commonly used to catch accidental disk or network access on the application's main thread
              .penaltyLog().build());


        //  Intent i = getIntent();

            //Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext);//,PrescAct.class);
            /* Bundle extras = i.getExtras();
             pid  = extras.getString("TAG_PATIENT_ID");*/



             Bundle b = getArguments();
             pid = b.getString("TAG_PATIENT_ID1");
            // System.out.println("Docpresc"+pid);

            // pid=getArguments().getString("TAG_PATIENT_ID1");
             System.out.println("Docpresc"+pid);



               // return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment, container, false);

             ailm = (EditText)getView().findViewById(R.id.ailment1);
             date = (EditText)getView().findViewById(R.id.date1);
             comment = (EditText)getView().findViewById(R.id.comment1);


            // if (savedInstanceState == null) {

                 new LoadPrescriptions().execute();
            //   }



            return view;
                // return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment, container, false);


        }





        class LoadPrescriptions extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {


            protected String doInBackground(String... args) {
                // Building Parameters

                getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                       public void run() {

                try {
                    List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
                    //pid=getArguments().getString("TAG_PATIENT_ID1");
                    // System.out.println("Docpresc"+pid);
                // getting JSON string from URL
                 params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("patient_id",pid));//search1.getText().toString()));
                 System.out.println("database"+pid);
                JSONObject json = jParser.makeHttpRequest(url_patient_presc, "GET", params);

                // Check your log cat for JSON reponse
            Log.d("All Patients: ", json.toString());


                    // Checking for SUCCESS TAG
                    int success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);

                    if (success == 1) {
                        // products found
                        // Getting Array of Products
                        products = json.getJSONArray(TAG_PRODUCTS);

                        //-----------------------------------
                        /*JSONObject product = products.getJSONObject(0);

                        ailm = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.ailment1);
                        ailm.setText(product.getString(TAG_AIL));*/
                        // looping through All Products
                        for (int i = 0; i < products.length(); i++) {
                            JSONObject c = products.getJSONObject(i);

                            // Storing each json item in variable
                                for(int m =0;m<2;m++){


                            String medicine = c.getString(TAG_MED[m]).toUpperCase();
                            String prescription = c.getString(TAG_PRESCRIPTION);



                            //String medicine[] = ((String) c.get(TAG_MED[i])).toUpperCase();
                        //  String qty1 = c.getString(TAG_D1).toUpperCase();
                        //  String qty2 = c.getString(TAG_D2).toUpperCase();
                        //  String qty3 = c.getString(TAG_D3).toUpperCase();
                            String dosage = c.getString(TAG_MED_D[m]);

                        //  String dsg_id = c.getString(TAG_DID).toUpperCase();
                            //String ail = c.getString(TAG_AIL).toUpperCase();
                        //getting 3 bytes from dosage1
                            String do1 = Character.toString(dosage.charAt(0));
                            String do2 = Character.toString(dosage.charAt(1));
                            String do3 = Character.toString(dosage.charAt(2));
                            //char do2 = dosage1.charAt(1);
                            //char do3 = dosage1.charAt(2);




                            ailm.setText(c.getString(TAG_AIL));
                            date.setText(c.getString(TAG_DATE));
                            comment.setText(c.getString(TAG_COM));


                            // creating new HashMap
                            HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

                            // adding each child node to HashMap key => value
                            System.out.println("medicine"+medicine+m);
                            if(medicine.equals("NULL")==false){
                                System.out.println("medicine in if"+medicine+m);
                            map.put(TAG_MED[i], medicine);
                            map.put(TAG_MED_D[i],dosage);
                            map.put(TAG_D1,do1);
                            map.put(TAG_D2,do2);
                            map.put(TAG_D3,do3);
                            map.put(TAG_PRESCRIPTION,prescription);
                        //  map.put(TAG_DID,dsg_id);


                            //if(map.containsValue(null)==false)

                            // adding HashList to ArrayList

                                productsList.add(map);
                                //if (productsList.get(m).containsValue(null))
                            //  productsList.remove(m);
                            System.out.println("productsList"+m+productsList);

                            }
                                }
                                }


                    } else {

                    }
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                       }
                       });
                return null;
            }


            /**
             * After completing background task Dismiss the progress dialog
             * **/
            protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
                // dismiss the dialog after getting all products
                //  pDialog.dismiss();
                // updating UI from Background Thread

                getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {

                        //ListAdapter 
                        adapter = new SimpleAdapter(
                                getActivity(), productsList,
                                R.layout.list_item2, new String[] {
                                    TAG_MED[0],TAG_D1,TAG_D2,TAG_D3,TAG_MED_D[0],TAG_PRESCRIPTION},
                                        // TAG_MED,TAG_MED1_D1},
                                    new int[] {R.id.med,R.id.d1,R.id.d2,R.id.d3,R.id.dos1,R.id.pres});
                                    //  new int[] {R.id.med,R.id.dos1});
                        // updating listview
                        //setListAdapter(adapter);

                        setListAdapter(adapter);



                    }

                 });

            }

        }
```

Here is the stack Trace:

```
06-20 12:44:34.767: E/AndroidRuntime(9394): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
06-20 12:44:34.767: E/AndroidRuntime(9394): java.lang.NullPointerException
06-20 12:44:34.767: E/AndroidRuntime(9394):     at com.example.actionbar.DocPresc1.onCreateView(DocPresc1.java:104)
06-20 12:44:34.767: E/AndroidRuntime(9394):     at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1460)
06-20 12:44:34.767: E/AndroidRuntime(9394):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:911)
06-20 12:44:34.767: E/AndroidRuntime(9394):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1088)
06-20 12:44:34.767: E/AndroidRuntime(9394):     at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:682)
06-20 12:44:34.767: E/AndroidRuntime(9394):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1444)
06-20 12:44:34.767: E/AndroidRuntime(9394):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executePendingTransactions(FragmentManager.java:461)
06-20 12:44:34.767: E/AndroidRuntime(9394):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter.finishUpdate(FragmentPagerAdapter.java:141)
06-20 12:44:34.767: E/AndroidRuntime(9394):     at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:1011)
06-20 12:44:34.767: E/AndroidRuntime(9394):     at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:880)
06-20 12:44:34.767: E/AndroidRuntime(9394):     at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.onMeasure(ViewPager.java:1374)
06-20 12:44:34.767: E/AndroidRuntime(9394):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15479)
06-20 12:44:34.767: E/AndroidRuntime(9394):     at android.widget.RelativeLayout.measureChildHorizontal(RelativeLayout.java:617)
06-20 12:44:34.767: E/AndroidRuntime(9394):     at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onMeasure(RelativeLayout.java:399)
06-20 12:44:34.767: E/AndroidRuntime(9394):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15479)
06-20 12:44:34.767: E/AndroidRuntime(9394):     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4828)
06-20 12:44:34.767: E/AndroidRuntime(9394):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
06-20 12:44:34.767: E/AndroidRuntime(9394):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15479)
06-20 12:44:34.767: E/AndroidRuntime(9394):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:833)
06-20 12:44:34.767: E/AndroidRuntime(9394):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:574)
06-20 12:44:34.767: E/AndroidRuntime(9394):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15479)
06-20 12:44:34.767: E/AndroidRuntime(9394):     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4828)
06-20 12:44:34.767: E/AndroidRuntime(9394):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
06-20 12:44:34.767: E/AndroidRuntime(9394):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:2359)
06-20 12:44:34.767: E/AndroidRuntime(9394):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15479)
06-20 12:44:34.767: E/AndroidRuntime(9394):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:1968)
06-20 12:44:34.767: E/AndroidRuntime(9394):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1214)
06-20 12:44:34.767: E/AndroidRuntime(9394):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1387)
06-20 12:44:34.767: E/AndroidRuntime(9394):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1107)
06-20 12:44:34.767: E/AndroidRuntime(9394):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:4464)
06-20 12:44:34.767: E/AndroidRuntime(9394):     at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:725)
06-20 12:44:34.767: E/AndroidRuntime(9394):     at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:555)
06-20 12:44:34.767: E/AndroidRuntime(9394):     at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:525)
06-20 12:44:34.767: E/AndroidRuntime(9394):     at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:711)
06-20 12:44:34.767: E/AndroidRuntime(9394):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
06-20 12:44:34.767: E/AndroidRuntime(9394):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
06-20 12:44:34.767: E/AndroidRuntime(9394):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
06-20 12:44:34.767: E/AndroidRuntime(9394):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4895)
06-20 12:44:34.767: E/AndroidRuntime(9394):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-20 12:44:34.767: E/AndroidRuntime(9394):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
06-20 12:44:34.767: E/AndroidRuntime(9394):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:994)
06-20 12:44:34.767: E/AndroidRuntime(9394):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:761)
06-20 12:44:34.767: E/AndroidRuntime(9394):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: did you figure out how to solve your problem?  Id like to apologize for the poor hospitality around here. Far to many developers on this site have god complexes and conveniently forget what it was like when they were new.Sometimes I think they purposely beat up on newbs to discourage them from trying to learn to protect their high salary's from deflating. Please do not be discouraged to post around here, i promise it gets better, once you have 100 or so points ppl start to respect your questions more

Answer (score 0):

```
ailm = (EditText)getView().findViewById(R.id.ailment1);
date = (EditText)getView().findViewById(R.id.date1);
comment = (EditText)getView().findViewById(R.id.comment1);
return view;
```

Fragment.getView() retuns what you have returned in onCreateView, so you can not use before onCreateView returns. Change this way

```
ailm = (EditText)view.findViewById(R.id.ailment1);
date = (EditText)view.findViewById(R.id.date1);
comment = (EditText)view.findViewById(R.id.comment1);
```

From the Android [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#getView%28%29):

```
Get the root view for the fragment's layout (the one returned by onCreateView(LayoutInflater, ViewGroup, Bundle)), if provided.

Returns
The fragment's root view, or null if it has no layout.
```

Comment: Thnx but i am still getting NUll Pointer on same line.